# How to get the total sum of counted values separated by commas in multiple rows, but disregarding zeroes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I want to count the number of values in multiple rows separated by commas--excluding those that have 0 values, using the following formula:

```
=SUM((LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C30:H30&",",",0",""))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C30:H30&",",",0",""),",",""))))
```

The formula was able to count the number of values for rows C30 to H30. However, it also added the rows with the zeroes entered in them. How could I make it skip or not count these rows?

Thank you so much for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Excel?

If you have the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use:

```
=LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(C30:H30=0,"",C30:H30)))- LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(C30:H30=0,"",C30:H30)),",",""))+1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ron! It worked!!! :)

Comment: Glad to help. Since my answer seems to satisfy your problem, I would appreciate it if you could mark it as accepted. You can read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.